# How to fill the mark in pgfplot legend

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I would like to create a graph using pgfplots. I don't like the legend symbol used for ybars and decided to go with a line legend entry and squares instead. How can I fill these marks, so that they have the same color as my bars?

Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[ybar,
xtick=data,
width=6cm,
height=5cm,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.7,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=6.5,
axis y line=left,
axis x line*=bottom,
xtick= {1,2,3,4,5,6},
bar width=4pt,
ytick={0,.1,.2,...,.7}
]
\addlegendimage{line legend,only marks,mark = square,color = black, fill =white}
\addlegendimage{line legend,only marks,mark = square,color = black, fill =gray}
\addlegendimage{line legend,only marks,mark = square,color = black, fill =black}
\addplot[xshift = 6pt,legend image post style={xshift=-6pt},color=black, fill =white, error bars, y dir=plus, y explicit]
coordinates{
(1,0.076844808) +- (1,0.043434089)  
(2,0.282802471) +-(2,0.143136578)};

\addplot[xshift = -3pt,legend image post style={xshift=3pt},color=black,fill= gray, error bars, y dir = plus, y explicit]
coordinates{
(3,0.026724427) +-(3,0.019038655)
(4,0.061169214) +-(4,0.024462018)   
(5,0.249852624) +-(5,0.047167041)   
(6,0.064414295) +-(6,0.045149736)};

\addplot[xshift = -3pt,legend image post style={xshift=3pt},color=black, fill = black, error bars, y dir=plus, y explicit]
coordinates{
(3,0.082127485) +- (3,0.045713902)          
(4,0.045611378) +- (4,0.018401772)
(5,0.299014506) +- (5,0.044026995)
(6,0.253207511) +- (6,0.320369411)
};
\legend{no, g/m, s}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `legend image code/.code` key to define how to draw the legend images. In your case, you could do the following:

```
legend image code/.code={%
    \draw[#1] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.15cm,0.15cm);
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[ybar,
xtick=data,
width=6cm,
height=5cm,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.7,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=6.5,
axis y line=left,
axis x line*=bottom,
xtick= {1,2,3,4,5,6},
bar width=4pt,
ytick={0,.1,.2,...,.7},
legend image code/.code={%
    \draw[#1] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.15cm,0.15cm);
}
]
\addplot[xshift = 6pt,legend image post style={xshift=-6pt},color=black, fill =white, error bars, y dir=plus, y explicit]
coordinates{
(1,0.076844808) +- (1,0.043434089)  
(2,0.282802471) +-(2,0.143136578)};

\addplot[xshift = -3pt,legend image post style={xshift=3pt},color=black,fill= gray, error bars, y dir = plus, y explicit]
coordinates{
(3,0.026724427) +-(3,0.019038655)
(4,0.061169214) +-(4,0.024462018)   
(5,0.249852624) +-(5,0.047167041)   
(6,0.064414295) +-(6,0.045149736)};

\addplot[xshift = -3pt,legend image post style={xshift=3pt},color=black, fill = black, error bars, y dir=plus, y explicit]
coordinates{
(3,0.082127485) +- (3,0.045713902)          
(4,0.045611378) +- (4,0.018401772)
(5,0.299014506) +- (5,0.044026995)
(6,0.253207511) +- (6,0.320369411)
};
\legend{no, g/m, s}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```